# Show/Hide where click event is triggered under one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**[progress](https://jsfiddle.net/zigzag/dnyux9qp/)**

```js
$(".button-toggle").click(function(e){
  $(this).parents.find('#second').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">
  <a href="#" class="buttong-toggle">
    <button>Show/Hide</button>
  </a>
</div>
    
<div id="second">
  larger section
</div>
```

As you can tell from the fiddle, this isn't working. I'm trying to figure out how do I traverse the DOM as 'this' event doesn't run within the context of the entire DOM so i suppose it can't locate #second ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code:
https://jsfiddle.net/orttv29j/

Fixes:

- Class name inside your anchor tag "class="button-toggle" and not "buttong".
- To target another class or id, you need to use that class or id name and not "this". this refers to the handler you used to fire that function, in this case button. `(You don't need to know where the target element is located whether in the same parent container or other, javascript does that itself by obtaining their id or class name as passed in the toggle function)`

```js
$(".button-toggle").click(function(e){
  $("#second").toggle();
});
```

```css
#first{
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
}
#second{
  background-color: gray;  
  min-height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">
  <a href="#" class="button-toggle">
    <button>Click</button>
  </a>
</div>

<div id="second">
  larger section
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. You on a roll bud. Already answered two of my questions this week. I like the way you format and detail your answer. Appreciate it!

Comment: @zigzag Thank you :) I try haha

Answer (score 1):

Here are some info changes -
class name : 'buttong-toggle' should be 'button-toggle'
$(this).parents - is function wont get the desired result need to use $(this).parents() - which is object
below is changes done.

```js
$(".button-toggle").click(function(e){
  $(this).parents().find('#second').toggle();    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">
  <a href="#" class="button-toggle">
    <button>Show/Hide</button>
  </a>
</div>

<div id="second">
  larger section
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeap, that did it.